# Django allow edit user password in admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

I know similar questions has been asked before, but I can't get this to work.

I have overriden the user admin template so i can show only specific fields of the user. This is working.

But I can't edit the user password becouse it appears hashed. I want to ad a link as it was before. 
I took a look at the solutions but they didnt worked. My code is as following:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fieldsets = ( 
    (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
    (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
    (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_superuser')}),
    (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
) 
list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
list_filter = ('is_active', 'groups')
password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label= ("Password"),
    help_text= ("Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see "
                "this user's password, but you can change the password "
                "using <a href=\"password/\">this form</a>."))

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

All of this works fine but the password is showing as a simple field and the text doesnt appears...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You will never "edit" the password because it is not saved "in clear" but encrypted at first.

You could add a link to a different view using `AdminPasswordChangeForm`.

Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AdminPasswordChangeForm)

Comment: And how can I add that link? I tried adding the field "password" as I showed in the question, but it didn't worked :S

Comment: In the user admin template, add a link to `admin/auth/user/{{ user.id }}/password/` or to a specific page to change the passowrd

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution:

```
password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label= ("Password"),
    help_text= ("Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see "
                "this user's password, but you can change the password "
                "using <a href=\"password/\">this form</a>."))
```

`this form` will link to it. The problem is that you've miss-placed this. It should be under the UserChangeForm. For example (depending on the User table you're using):

```
class AdminUserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(
        help_text="Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see "
                  "this user's password, but you can change the password "
                  "using <a href=\"password/\">this form</a>."
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
        )

    def clean_password(self):
        ...
        return self.initial["password"]
```

---

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    ...
    fieldsets = (
        ('Login', {
            'fields': [
                'email',
                'password',
            ]
        }),
        ...
    )

    ...
    form = AdminUserChangeForm
    add_form = AdminUserCreationForm
```